# Do monsters respawn in Half Life?

Tags: half-life

Title says all. I want to know whether mobs respawn in Half Life because I'm stuck in one level where I have not enough ammo to face current enemies (they take several shots) and I'm thinking of going back to check what I may have left behind.

Comment: All singleplayer half-life games, or games games based on src or goldsrc have multiple save slots and quick saving. You can make as many saves as you want and load them at any time. So if you wonder if its OK to do something, save, then try it. Just don't accidentally quick save midway down a fatal fall.(like I did halfway through an Hl1 mod once)

Comment: There's always your handy dandy crowbar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No; NPCs generally do not respawn in Half Life. I'm not aware of exceptions, so cleared areas should remain clear for your backtracking pleasure.

Comment: Correct, with the at least the one exception that Armin described.

Answer (score 24):

Monsters/Enemies respawn only at certain locations. ( Holds true for every difficulty level )

This is a list of locations sorted by game playtrough

- Office Complex (map c1a2) / Headcrabs

  The room with the flooded room and electricity. There is a ventilation shaft through you which have to process to advance, inside is a horizontal ventilator that is spinning ( it will kill you if you don't crouch). Above the ventilator is a hole with infinitely spawning headcrabs. They do always fall onto the ventilator and die.
- We've Got Hostiles ( map c1a3b ) / Marines

  The first time you get to the surface. The open area has marines, an [V-22 Osprey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) and the area is constantly bombarded with artillery. Osprey is periodically dropping four marines behind electrified fence which you cannot get over. ( you can using grenade jump, but you are not supposed to ). As long as Osprey is operational and you keep killing marines, infinitely many will drop from it. You cannot collect infinite ammo as there is no effective way to kill the marines.
- We've Got Hostiles ( map c1a3c ) / Marines

  Just after the previous encounter. Open the shaft door, in the large vertical shaft with the large ventilator at the bottom. Two marines will constantly drop from the Osprey with the same rules as the marines on the surface before. This time you can collect the ammo, but it is very difficult to do it efficiently.
- Surface Tension ( map c2a5e ) / Marines / Infinite machine gun ammo

  At the end of this map inside a military base. Another Osprey is circling around a large asphalt area where are two Alien Grunts and is dropping infinitely many marines. This time you can get as much machine gun ammo as you wish. 
  First kill the Alien Grunts, then go to the right side of the map. There is a large cannon. Aim it at the nearby wall, be careful not to aim to close as you will damage yourself, and weight down the fire button. Marines will gladly run into the explosions.
  Result after 10 minutes:

  [image]
- Gonarch's Lair ( map c4a2a ) / Headcrabs

  The second stage of the fight with Gonarch ( headcrab queen ). In the middle is a chasm with three ledges and an crevice. Inside the crevice and in two of the ledges are infinitely spawning headcrabs. They spawn out of thin air if you are not very close ( stand on an ledge above the chasm ).

  [image]
- Nihilanth ( map c4a3 ) / Alien Slave , Alien Controller

  The last boss fight in half life. Every couple of normal attacks, Nihilanth ( boss ) fires a homing green portal towards the player. Every time that portal is destroyed, either by hitting the player or hitting the wall, an alien slave ( vortigaunt ) or an alien controller is spawned. This will occur only if there are two or less monsters already present( not counting Nihilanth ).

  Trick: You can destroy the green homing portal using the Hornet Gun, to avoid being teleported away from the main fight.

Comment: Fun fact, but it doesn't really answer the question at hand.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar It answers `Do monsters respawn in Half Life?`, maybe you misread the question.

Comment: Except it doesn't. The question is "Do enemies respawn?" and your answer is "there is a highly specific place where a highly specific enemy will spawn infinitely." So nothing to do with respawning, and only tangentially relevant to the actual question.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Sou you are saying that my answer where monsters do and do not respawn,which basically says that they do not except for one location, does not answer the question Do monsters respawn in Half Life? :)

Comment: @Armin An answer that is explicit is easier to read/understand. A reader has to read the whole question and think about it before they can infer that your answer is "no, but…" It doesn't help that your answer starts by sounding like you're saying the opposite. What would make this perfect is… well, I'll edit it in. ;)

Comment: There's an area in Gonarch's Lair where you can go into [a small cave with a small room with partly missing floor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=5VfxNh1S0Gs#t=364s), there will always spawn headcrabs there. At least they did for me on hard.

Comment: @Bobby Thank you. I have researched and updated the answer.